# Databricks parquet read taking too long

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have two separate set of files with different schemas stored in parquet files in Azure blob storage, both are both stored in month/day/hour sub folders.

I need to process the files on an hourly schedule, which means i can just load the most recent files from the 1st schema. However, i need to join onto a record from the 2nd schema which may be at any possible time in the past. So in order to join onto the correct record, i need to load the entire dataset from the 2nd schema.

I'm using `spark.read.parquet(rootlocation)` before using the result in a join. This read is understandable taking a long time (almost an hour). Does anyone know of any strategies to optimise this? I don't seem to be getting any parallelism as i only have 1 job.

Answer (score 2):

You can speedup the process by providing schemas when reading the table or both tables. Otherwise, Spark will need to discover all partitions, figure out schema, etc., and when you have a lot of files (especially small), then it may take a lot of time (also check that you don't have `.option("mergeSchema", "true")` set):

```scala
val schema = "col1 long, col2 string, ..."
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).load("path")
```

Alternatively you can switch to Delta Lake tables from Parquet - in that case, schema is stored in the Delta log, and could be fetched much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - i've tried providing the schema using that syntax but unfortunately its taking the same amount of time (about 40 minutes). Does this mean it's not possible to reduce any further with the data in its current form?

Comment: without detailed information it's hard to say, as you may spend all the time, for example, discovering all available partitions if you have overpartitioned table with a lot of partitions and small files

Comment: In case it helps clear things up - Spark does not use the partition information you provide it until _AFTER_ it's scanned everything, your only real option to performance is delta if you are suffering from number of files / partitions.  Even if you don't use any other delta feature, this particular problem (opening a dataset without ever touching your code for 10's of minutes) is solved.

Comment: Okay, thanks for advice. Unfortunately in this scenario I'm only the data consumer, not the producer so i don't believe delta is an option. Guess I'm stuck with the 40 minutes.